# How to create horizontal Multi-page apps in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I know Streamlit has Multi-page app feature now as suggested below

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/multipage-apps/create-a-multipage-app

However, it appears to have the menu for these page on the sidebar.

I am looking for ways to make this appear as horizontal tabs on main page.

Streamlit Component, https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-option-menu-is-a-simple-streamlit-component-that-allows-users-to-select-a-single-item-from-a-list-of-options-in-a-menu/20514

helps u to have horizontal menu app, but the problem there is unlike Multi-page app where one page can have a separate script of it's own, options-menu want it to be written as part of one script using if condition.

Is there a better solution?